# Removing rows from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have this `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id1=LETTERS[sample(26,100,replace = T)],id2=LETTERS[sample(26,100,replace = T)],stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and this `vector`:

```
vec <- LETTERS[sample(26,10,replace = F)]
```

I want to remove from `df` any row which either `df$id1` or `df$id2` are not in `vec`

Is there any faster way of finding the row indices which meet this condition than this:

```
rm.idx <- which(!apply(df,1,function(x) all(x %in% vec)))
```

Comment: If you have only these two elements to check, `which(!(df$id1 %in% vec & df$id2 %in% vec))`

Answer (score 2):

I used `dplyr` with such script

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(!(df$id1 %in%  vec)|!(df$id2 %in% vec))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping over the columns might be faster than over rows.  So, use `lapply` to loop over the columns, create a `list` of logical `vector`s with `%in%`, use `Reduce` with `|` to check whether there are any TRUE values for each corresponding row and use that to subset the 'df'

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `%in%`, vec)),]
```

If we need both elements, then replace `|` with `&`

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, `%in%`, vec)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
rm.idx <- unique(which(!(df$id1 %in% vec) | !(df$id2 %in% vec)))
```

is also fast.

Comment: you don't need to wrap it in `unique`; `which` will give you an index of the row-numbers that meet the condition (which are unique by design)